# How to add user as developer based on SSH key?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I am using gitlab and I need to add a user to a project in gitlab. For this purpose I click on Settings and then on Members. A form appears where I need to search for people and define the Project Access. Project Access will be developer, so that will be OK. However, the person is not a GitLab user. Is there any way I can add him to the project without asking him to register to gitlab? If I can do it using a git bash command, then that's fine too. I have his GitHub username and public SSH key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now having a GitLab user account is a prerequisite for write access to a repository (github has the option for read-write deployment keys, however, gitlab just has read-only deployment keys ATM). But without a user, how should gitlab know the privilege level? That's all managed using users in gitlab.

Comment: GitLab could define a concept to handle this case. For instance a concept of foreign user. If I could add a foreign user by URL and the foreign user's acceptance would generate a user for him, then this problem could be easy to overcome. I believe you are right, but will not accept your answer just yet, to see whether others have other information.